# How can I recreate the behavior of MSN Messenger with regards to opening new chat windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I want create something that looks like the MSN Messenger chat forms.

I am looking to create the following behavior:

1. You double-click a user on your user list
2. Messenger opens a form for that user, with your previous chat log with that user
3. You go back to your user list and double-click that user again
4. Messenger brings the previously opened form back into focus without creating another form

How can I recreate this behavior in C# WinForms

Comment: There are a number of questions in here, most of which should be their own question.  I'd recommend asking some of those as separate questions (or see if they have already been asked) and then taking the aggregate of the answers to help you with your broad solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dictionary<Guid, Form> dic = new Dictionary<Guid, Form>();
    public Form ShowForm(Guid userId)
    {
        Form form;
        if (!dic.TryGetValue(userId, out form))
        {
            form = new Form();
            dic.Add(userId, form);
        }
        return form;
    }
```

Comment: Right idea, but it is critical to implement the form's FormClosed event to remove the form from the dictionary again.  Not doing so produces an ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: you can handle FormClosed event(e.cancle=true) and only hide it unless you want complete closed that you must remove it from dictionary and then close form